# I accidentally stopped wiping my hard drive half way through. Why won't my system boot?

Tags: boot

I was trying to wipe my hard drive but then accidentally cancelled. About 30 seconds later Ubuntu powered down and now I can't get back on. What has happened to my OS? What does this mean?

Comment: So you wanted to wipe the HDD while Ubuntu was running from it?

Comment: Well I had just started wiping it but yes i did

Comment: "I was trying to wipe my hard drive but then accidentally cancelled" eh. So wipe it again? Like this is worded you wanted to wipe it so why is the "not booting" an issue?  Reinstall an OS.

Answer (score 5):

Your OS is stored on the hard drive. If you were wiping the drive, some of the files necessary for starting the system have been wiped.

You will need a bootable usb drive with Ubuntu (or another os) installed on it. You can boot from the usb drive, and use the live os to finish wiping your hard drive, or re-install Ubuntu on the hard drive.

When you wipe a hard drive you must expect the content of the drive to be destroyed. That includes both the OS and your personal files. If the wiping was stopped before it completed, some files may still exist.

Comment: Yeah, I'll do that but will the old os still be there, or is my old os gone?

Comment: @AdamWhite, When you wipe the hard disk drive, you must expect that whatever was written to it will be wiped, gone (overwritten with zero bytes or some random data). Depending on the method you used to wipe the drive 'half way', some data [files] might or might not be possible to recover.

Comment: When I reinstall ubuntu I can get rid of the old os right?

Comment: Yes, @AdamWhite.